# javascript - Arrange table in numerical order

Tags: javascript

Say I have a table.

```
<table><tr>
<td>ID</td><td>Item</td></tr><tr>
<td>1</td><td>Air</td></tr><tr>
<td>7</td><td>Water</td></tr><tr>
<td>3</td><td>Grass</td></tr><tr>
<td>2</td><td>Dirt</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to arrange the table based on the IDs of the items. Which means I want to arrange the table to something like this:

```
<table><tr>
<td>ID</td><td>Item</td></tr><tr>
<td>1</td><td>Air</td></tr><tr>
<td>2</td><td>Dirt</td></tr><tr>
<td>3</td><td>Grass</td></tr><tr>
<td>7</td><td>Water</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<table id="myTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="sort_id">1</td><td>Air</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sort_id">7</td><td>Water</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sort_id">3</td><td>Grass</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sort_id">2</td><td>Dirt</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var rows = $('#myTbl > tbody').children('tr').get();
        rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            var anum = parseInt($(a).find(".sort_id").text(), 10);
            var bnum = parseInt($(b).find(".sort_id").text(), 10);
            return anum - bnum;
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            $('#myTbl > tbody').append(rows[i]);
        }
    });

</script>
```